# Use waynebloss/BindingListView with DevExpress XtraGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bindingsource, xtragrid

I have several DevExpress.XtraGrid (DataGrids) and would like to filter them all from once place in code.

So I my idea is to filter the underlying BindingSource. This means the List of BindingSource needs to implement the IBindingListView. So I came across the [BindingListView](https://github.com/waynebloss/BindingListView) project which seems to fit perfectly.

And it works perfect for DataGridView but not for the XtraGrid.

I place two DataGridViews and two XtraGrids in my WinForm and the following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingList<Person> persons = new BindingList<Person>();

        persons.Add(new Person("Ray", "Rochester", 18));
        persons.Add(new Person("Scott", "Cupertino", 33));
        persons.Add(new Person("Samuel", "Boston", 54));


        BindingListView<Person> blvPersons = new BindingListView<Person>(persons);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = blvPersons;
        dataGridView2.DataSource = blvPersons;

        gridControl1.DataSource = blvPersons;
        gridControl2.DataSource = blvPersons;

        blvPersons.ApplyFilter(delegate (Person customer) { return customer.Age > 20; });
    }
}


public class Person
{
    public Person(string name, string city, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        City = city;
        Age = age;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string  City { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

The line gridControl1.DataSource = blvPersons;  gives me:

> {"Unable to cast object of type 'Equin.ApplicationFramework.ObjectView`1[GridView_Test.Person]' to type 'GridView_Test.Person'."}

First lines of stack trace:

> at (Object )
>      at DevExpress.Data.Access.DataListDescriptor.FastPropertyDescriptor.GetValue(Object component)
>      at DevExpress.Data.Helpers.BaseListDataControllerHelper.GetRowValue(Int32 listSourceRow, Int32 column, OperationCompleted completed)
>      at DevExpress.Data.DataController.GetRowValue(Int32 controllerRow, Int32 column, OperationCompleted completed)
>      at DevExpress.Data.BaseListSourceDataController.GetRowValue(Int32 controllerRow, Int32 column, OperationCompleted completed)

Now I'm stuck. Anybody any idea?

Comment: I would declare  BindingList<Person> persons in global space so other methods can get access to the List instead of using the binding source.  Then filter the BindingList instead of the binding Source.

Comment: Global space. It's just an example, simple as possible. BindingList<T> doesn't implement a filter as far as I know. I would need to make something like "persons = new BindingList<Person>(...)"  Which doesn't seems to elegant to me. I would have to set DataSource on all GridViews again.

Comment: Call DevExpress support mate to provide you a way to let their component not creating "fast" property descriptors. With their implementation they are breaking the whole idea of property descriptors.

Comment: You still are going to have to set the DataSource on all grid because the grids will not automatically update.  Usually you have to set the DGV DataSource to null and then back to a source to get the DGVs to refresh.